Anchoring a10x12gazebo from big lots
Setting a 12x10 metal hard top gazebo in an existing 12x12 area set with 12 inch pavers. Will the pavers work to anchor it down.If not looking for ideas. Thank you

If you have some wind, the pavers will just hit you harder.  Think of the top as just a big sail/something a bit of wind can pick up.  You want anchors deep into the ground.

No, the pavers are not suitable to hold down the gazebo.
You need  Tie Down Anchors  like these. Connecting strong cables or chain to the gazebo and anchors will not make it immovable, but it will keep it from blowing away in most anything but an exceptionally strong wind.

Yep, I was gonna suggest helical anchors.

12" pavers might help it land upright after it flies away in a good wind/rain storm. You need to think about pouring some concrete supports in the ground and anchoring the gazebo posts to them. Check your locals for what is actually needed / required.
